# How to structure and where to implement parts of a WPF Prism App (music player)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, prism

I tried to create a WPF music player with basic MVVM, but I reached some limits with too many dependencies, so I chose **Prism** to build my application modular in a (hopefully) better way.

I already watched and read alot stuff about Prism and created some basic and extended example apps to get better knowledge.
My only really problem is that I don't know how to structure and where to implement parts of the application because of it's dependencies.

My structure looks like this now:

[image]

In `App.Core.Music` I got all interfaces and some shared objects/enums for other modules related to music stuff like:

- **IMusicManager**:
  Contains mapped playback methods and binding props, accessable trough DI container as singleton and shared like this:

  ```
  public class MusicModule : IModule
  {
      private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;

      public MusicModule(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
      {
          _unityContainer = unityContainer;
      }

      public void Initialize()
      {
          var musicSettings = XmlHelper.Get<CurrentMusicSettings>(CurrentMusicSettings.FileName) ?? new CurrentMusicSettings();
          var playlistSettings = XmlHelper.Get<PlaylistSettings>(PlaylistSettings.FileName) ?? new PlaylistSettings();

          _unityContainer.RegisterInstance<ICurrentMusicSettings>(musicSettings, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
          _unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IPlaylistSettings>(playlistSettings, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
          _unityContainer.RegisterType<IMusicManager, MusicManager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

          // Getting the music manager by container because of its dependencies
          var musicManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMusicManager>();
          musicManager.Load();
      }
  }

  namespace App.Music.UI.ViewModels
  {
      public class PlayBarViewModel : BindableBase
      {
          private IMusicManager _musicManager;

          public PlayBarViewModel(IMusicManager musicManager)
          {    
              _musicManager = musicManager;

              BackwardCommand = new DelegateCommand(MusicManager.GoBackward);
              ForwardCommand = new DelegateCommand(MusicManager.GoForward);
          }

          // Bound like <Slider Value="{Binding MusicManager.CurrentTrackPosition}" />
          public IMusicManager MusicManager
          {
              get { return _musicManager; }
              set { SetProperty(ref _musicManager, value); }
          }

          // Command Properties...
      }
  }
  ```
- **IMusicEngine**: real instance for playback, included in **IMusicManager**
- ...some other own interfaces included in IMusicManager (not relevant)
- **ITrack**
- **IPlaylist**:
  Contains **ITrack** and some methods

So in the `App.Music` module are the interface implementations and objects like `PlaylistBase`, `Playlist`, `Track` and `TrackBase` which can't be accessed from outside the module.
Does this make sense because I'll need ITrack "instances" in other modules and when I want to create some, should i get them by requesting some of the DI Container and the manipulating them?

In the `App.Core.Settings` are just some settings interfaces like `IConfigurationSettings : ISettings` which is implemented in the main/shell project App because they are needed in the bootstrapper.
Other settings implemented in the `App.Music.Settings` are needed there because of XML serialization.

So all music related modules need the App.Music module first to be loaded which I do like this in the `App.config`:

```
<modules>
  <module assemblyFile="Modules\App.Music.dll" moduleType="..." moduleName="MusicModule" startupLoaded="True" />
  <module assemblyFile="Modules\App.Music.UI.dll" moduleType="..." moduleName="MusicUIModule" startupLoaded="True">
    <dependencies>
        <dependency moduleName="MusicModule" />
    </dependencies>
  </module>
</modules>
```

---

To my questions above I want to ask if this is kind of ok and future manipulatable/extendable? What could/should I do better?

Comment: Do not use ServiceLocator, especially when you have the container right there.  It's an anti pattern, and should be avoided if possible.  Also, not sure why you felt the need to separate your UI from the module, but hey if that's what you want to do, go for it.

Comment: @BrianLagunas Thanks for the tip, I'll change that (: I thought I should seperate my application a bit more, 'cause in your first prism pluralsight course (btw. it's great) you created an extra module for a StatusBar for example. Other short question: Should I replace Events with PubSubEvents that are not related to ViewModels like for notifications between instances in one module?

Comment: I only did that to demonstrate modularity, not to promote separating your UI from your ViewModels.  If you're not sharing your VMs or Views, no need to separate.  Place events where they belong. If only one module will use an event, define it in the module, and not in a core or shared assembly.

Comment: @BrianLagunas Alright, thanks for your effort! If you are willing to summarize your points shortly as an answer, I will accept it as solution (:

Answer (score 0):

> So in the App.Music module are the interface implementations and objects like PlaylistBase, Playlist, Track and TrackBase which can't be accessed from outside the module. Does this make sense because I'll need ITrack "instances" in other modules

It's totally fine, [e.g. in Prism documentation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/70-CommunicatingBetweenLooselyCoupledComponents.md):

> Another method of cross-module communication is through shared services. When the modules are loaded, modules add their services to the service locator. Typically, services are registered and retrieved from a service locator by common interface types. This allows modules to use services provided by other modules without requiring a static reference to the module. Service instances are shared across modules, so you can share data and pass messages between modules.
>
> In the Stock Trader Reference Implementation (Stock Trader RI), the Market module provides an implementation of IMarketFeedService. The Position module consumes these services by using the shell application's dependency injection container, which provides service location and resolution. The IMarketFeedService is meant to be consumed by other modules, so it can be found in the StockTraderRI.Infrastructure common assembly, but the concrete implementation of this interface does not need to be shared, so it is defined directly in the Market module and can be updated independently of other modules.

Comment: Yes I already thought that this is fine, but I questioned if this makes sense, because it's not a service which is used like 2-3 times, instead they are kind of "local" POCO objects created many times.. won't it take performance if I use the ServiceLocator every time instead of creating directly an instance?